# Dealing with cache file locks when using EntityValue in ParallelMap

Tags: parallelization, curated-data, windows, version-11

I'm trying to run the following (naturally, I have FAR more zip codes and a much longer list of properties, both truncated for speed of the example):

```
zipCodes={"40220","46202","46077","40202","80301","80304","90210","90211"};
zipProperties = {
                 EntityProperty["ZIPCode", "AggregateHouseholdIncome"], 
                 EntityProperty["ZIPCode", "AverageHouseValue"], 
                 EntityProperty["ZIPCode", "Employment"], 
                 EntityProperty["ZIPCode", "Population",{"Gender"->"Female"}], 
                 EntityProperty["ZIPCode", "Population",{"Gender"->"Male"}]
                };
zipData = ParallelMap[
   With[
     {zip = #},
     Join[{zip}, Entity["ZIPCode", zip][#]& /@ zipProperties]
     ] &,
   zipCodes
   ];
```

and I'm getting:

```
(kernel 1) CreateFile::filex :  C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\Knowledgebase\u8cfm00s2kat\u8cfm00s2kat-1709886844729300217.dat.lock already exists.
(kernel 3) EntityValue::nodat :  Unable to download data. Some or all results may be missing.
(kernel 8) ...more of the same...
```

I'm assuming the `nodat` error is just a legitimate absence of data, though it could also signify a lack of a result from too many simultaneous requests. I've had that happen before with `FinancialData` and had to go back and re-retreive values for `Missing[]` results where I knew that they HAD to exist (like closing prices for valid ticker symbols on dates when trading occurred).

Anyone knows how to get Wolfram curated data from a parallelized process without running into locks?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For a workaround, try `ParallelEvaluate[EntityFramework\`$UseFileCache = False];`

Comment: Interesting workaround. Thank you. Though, ideally, I don't want to stop using cache. Otherwise, subsequent runs on same zip codes will always go to reacquire data, wasting lots of time. A different list of zip codes could have many of the zip codes which I've already ran. I guess I could create my own cache. Gives me something to think about.